# Diff update of a key of a Simperium object

Tags: simperium

Is it possible to send to simperium an update of value on an object without sending the whole value?

I've been thinking about having a list with a lot of small "entry" objects as a value of the simperium object but I can't seem to find a way to only send an update telling simperium to add an entry to that list. If I send something like `{ "list":{"a":"new object"}}`, the whole existing list is replaced. How can this work with Simplenote? If Simplenote sends the whole body every time, it wouldn't be that fast…

I'm also afraid that updating the whole list would mean the whole list would be downloaded on the other client and that's just a waste since the data I want to keep will be pretty static.

And I can't divide into multiple objects because I need to share the list with other users.

I'm thinking I'll probably make the entries as values in the simperium object itself, so I can make small updates but that seems kind of a hackish way to do it and I'd rather have an ordered list…

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Hello Carlos,

Simperium libraries indeed send + receive deltas, instead of the entire documents all over. May i ask you what technology are you currently developing for?.

Comment: Yeah, I've been digging in the iOS code and I saw there's a delta for strings but there isn't for lists. I'm considering using just a big string of formatted lines and hope it'll work.

Comment: Are you developing for iOS?. (Currently Simperium doesn't support 'Embedded objects', one solution would be to serialize those objects as json and treat them as strings, which is what's the 'Embedded Objects' pull request does).

Comment: Yes. That's an idea. I was considering just lines since the app would primarily just add stuff to the end, avoiding less conversions but I guess I would have to load them all for display… I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: No problem Carlos. If you have any issues with the integration, please, let me know, would love to help!.